# Cannot disable submit button by $invalid while page load

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to <strike>invalidate and</strike> disable the submit button on the load of the page, as not entering text into textbox is invalid, but my code is not working, can someone please provide the solution.

```
<div id="reg_bground">           
    <div id="formdiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="valCtrl">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate>
            <div style="font-family:calibri; font-size:30px; font-weight:bolder;">
                <span>Register:</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Name:</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required><br>
                <p ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">*Please insert the name</p>
            </div>
            <input type="number">
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should tell clearly how it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially check for `$dirty` state in the submit button for disabled status.

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
```

`$dirty` is only set to `true` when user has meddled with the `myForm.user` input, which is not the case on page load. Instead, try checking the `$pristine` state (or `!$dirty`)

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$pristine || myForm.user.$invalid">
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the dirty check in the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled=" ̶m̶y̶F̶o̶r̶m̶.̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶$̶d̶i̶r̶t̶y̶ ̶&̶&̶ ̶ myForm.user.$invalid">
```

Answer (score 0):

> The field content is valid

$invalid working when you enter a input and input doesn't match your pattern .
you must use $error.required for your goal.

follwing will work

```
<div id="reg_bground">
     <div id="formdiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="valCtrl">
            <form name="myForm" novalidate>
                <div style="font-family:calibri; font-size:30px; font-
        weight:bolder;">
                    <span>Register:</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Name:</span><br>
                    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required><br>
                    <p ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && 
      myForm.user.$error.required">*Please insert the name</p>
                </div>
                <input type="number">
                <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && 
     myForm.user.$error.required">
            </form>
         </div>
```